# How to change dtypes of numpy array for tensorflow

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am creating a neural network in tensorflow and I have created the placeholders like this:

```
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (None,n_input), name = "input_tensor")
output_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (None,n_classes), name = "output_tensor")
```

During the training process, I was getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 150, in <module>
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x_train[i: i + 1], Y: y_train[i: i + 1]})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I identified that is because of the different datatypes of my x_train and y_train to the datatypes of the placeholders.

My x_train looks somewhat like this:

```
array([[array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])],
   [array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])],
   [array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])]], dtype=object)
```

It was initially a dataframe like this:

```
0  [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
1  [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
2  [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
```

I did `x_train = train_x.values` to get the numpy array

And y_train looks this:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

x_train has dtype object and y_train has dtype float64.

What I want to know is that how I can change the datatypes of my training data so that it can work well with the tensorflow placeholders. Or please suggest if I am missing something.

Comment: @BradSolomon That was just because I did not paste the whole print output. I will edit it.

Comment: @BradSolomon It is a single column and not for the index. I misunderstood you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x_train` is a nested object containing arrays, so you have to unpack it and reshape it. Here's a general purpose hack:

```
def unpack(a, aggregate=[]):
    for x in a:
        if type(x) is float:
            aggregate.append(x)
        else:
            unpack(x, aggregate=aggregate)
    return np.array(aggregate)
x_train = unpack(x_train.values).reshape(x_train.shape[0],-1)
```

Once you've got a dense array (`y_train` is already dense), you can use a function like the following:

```
def cast(placeholder, array):
    dtype = placeholder.dtype.as_numpy_dtype
    return array.astype(dtype)

x_train, y_train = cast(X,x_train), cast(Y,y_train)
```

Comment: If I do x_train = np.array(list(x_train)), I am getting [0]. It should be list(xtrain.values). Then I will end with something like this:

[[array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])]
 [array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])]
 [array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])]]
with dtype again object. If I proceed with it, it gives me:

sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x_train[i: i + 1], Y: y_train[i: i + 1]})

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: What if you use [as_matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html)?

Comment: Doing x_train = train_x.as_matrix() gives the same result as what I mentioned for  train_x.values in the question.

Comment: Edited to include a hack that should do what you want, tested it on a dataframe nested like the one you showed, but it should work with just about any, as long as the row indexing the datapoint matches y.

Answer (score 0):

It is little hard to guess what shape you want your data to be, but I am guessing one of the two combinations which you might be looking for. I will also try to simulate your data in Pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]], 
[[[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]],
[[[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]]], columns = ['Mydata'])
print(df)

x = df.Mydata.values
print(x.shape)
print(x)
print(x.dtype)
```

Output:

```
                               Mydata
0  [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
1  [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
2  [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]

(3,)
[list([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]])
 list([[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
 list([[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]])]
object
```

**Combination 1**

```
y = [item for sub_list in x for item in sub_list]
y = np.array(y, dtype = np.float32)
print(y.dtype, y.shape)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
float32 (6, 3)
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]]
```

**Combination 2**

```
y = [sub_list for sub_list in x]
y = np.array(y, dtype = np.float32)
print(y.dtype, y.shape)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
float32 (3, 2, 3)
[[[ 1.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  1.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  1.  0.]
  [ 1.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  1.  0.]]]
```

Comment: as per your combination 2, if I do y = np.array(y, dtype = np.float32), I will get 'setting an array element with a sequence'. Doing np.array(y) gives the same structure as what I have mentioned in the question. And the challenge was that I was not able to change the dtype just by using dtype = np.float32 as I was getting the same error